# Release does not exist - Kubernetes, GItlab CI /CD

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab

I had already setup kubernetes cluster and enabled gitlab auto devops. While deploying application on kubernetes cluster i am getting some issue. Below is the issue details. while i am able to deploy my application through kubernetes dashboard.

```
Create secret…
secret “gitlab-registry” deleted
secret/gitlab-registry replaced
$ deploy
secret/review-staging-tqz4ro-secret replaced
Deploying new release…
Release “review-staging-tqz4ro” does not exist. Installing it now.
Error: release review-staging-tqz4ro failed: timed out waiting for the condition
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Comment: `Error: release review-staging-tqz4ro failed: timed out waiting for the condition` Most likely your application fails to start in a timely matter or is crash looping. Can you check the logs? And check `kubectl get pods` you should be able to see if it is crash looping quite quickly